# whats the proper way to automate a website

Tags: django

what I'm trying to accomplish is a site that obtains data from other sites via scraping or using a sites rss feed to store things like the image path, title of the story and text in my database so That I can display it in a techmeme or drudge report like fashion.

I want this to happen every 5 or so hours and I want to delete very old things, and I want it all to happen without me having to do it manually. I have been advised on using rabbitmq with celery. now i'm being advised to use redis.

I just watched a video last night on youtube by new circle training and the speaker said twice on rabbitmq and not using it as a backend and he said if you get anything from what I'm saying please get that. But I also know people have biases sometimes for stacks and languages. I have none, I just want my project to work.

To sum up what I'm saying whats an efficient way to automate tasks so they will scrape sites for the image path, title and text store them in my database so I can use it later and display it. as I said I want it to be similar to the drudge report or techmeme.

Answer (score 0):

I found redis much more useful and more reliable than rabbitmq. 
I would create a django application, where celery and redis would be connected. Couple of models to store basic information like: site from which was link scrapped, link, date and other stuff you wish.

Also I recommend using [beautiful soup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4), [python requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), if you are making a lot of requests, try to consider using multiple proxies with multiple user agents.

Comment: Thanks For the positive feed back. I think I will go back to redis and i am already using beatifulsoup and requests.